# jsf 2.0 @FacesConverter forClass BigDecimal not working?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, mojarra

I'm using Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02) on Glassfish 3.1.1.
When I use

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=BigDecimal.class)
...
<h:outputText value="#{product.netValue}"/>
```

but when I change to:

```
@FacesConverter("priceConverter")
...
<h:outputText value="#{product.netValue}" converter="priceConverter"/>
```

It works. Is there a bug in Mojarra?
I also use `@FacesConverter(forClass=String.class)` with no problem. Only BigDecimal is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how mojarra handles multiple converters for the same type. JSF comes with a default BigDecimalConverter. If i have to guess i would say that the jsf converter is used instead of yours